# Как установить population для внутренних коллекций

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

столкнулся со следующей проблемой когда в `MongoDB` создаю новую статью хочу записать ее в ее категорию. Все отлично внутренние коллекции и тп, но когда вытягиваю данные через

**population** - он отдает как и надо мне вместо ссылки на посты - их содержимое. Но у постов тоже есть внутренняя коллекция - *Автор статьи* - как вместо айди автора мне выдавать его данные?

[image: структура запроса]

Пробовал использовать сразу два population

```
const posts = CategoriesModel.find().populate({ path: 'articles' })
const posts = posts.populate({path: 'author'})
res.json(posts)
```

но безуспешно...

заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

**Раньше код был:**

```
const categories = await CategoriesModel.find().populate({
        path: 'articles'
})
```

**Стал:**

```
const categories = await CategoriesModel.find().populate({
        path: 'articles',
        populate: { path: 'author' },
})
```

[image: исправленная версия]